# Uncaught ReferenceError: postRefreshPage is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un problema al llamar la función `postRefreshPage()` en un botón que supone debería regresar a la página del menú y enviar los datos del usuario para que la sesión se mantenga iniciada.

Este es el botón:

```
<button  class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" aria-label="Right Align" style="float: right;" onclick="postRefreshPage();">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
&nbsp; Regresar al menu
</button>
```

Y esta es la función:

```
function postRefreshPage(){
    var theForm, newInput1, newInput2;
    // Se crea el <form>
    theForm = document.createElement('form');
    theForm.action = 'pruebas/checklogin.php';
    theForm.method = 'post';
    // Se crean los <input>s en el form y les damos nombre y valor
    newInput1 = document.createElement('input');
    newInput1.type = 'hidden';
    newInput1.name = 'username';
    newInput1.value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['user']?>";
    newInput2 = document.createElement('input');
    newInput2.type = 'hidden';
    newInput2.name = 'password';
    newInput2.value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['pass']?>";
    // Lo juntamos todo...
    theForm.appendChild(newInput1);
    theForm.appendChild(newInput2);
    // ...y ahora al DOM...
    document.getElementById('hidden_form_container').appendChild(theForm);
    // ...y lo mandamos
    theForm.submit();
}
```

Y me lanza este error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: postRefreshPage is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Esta página esta en un servidor y es donde me lanza el error, pero cuando la corría en local todo funcionaba bien.

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: El tipo de error que mencionas se suele deber a que la función _ postRefreshPage_ no es visible o localizada por el onclick. Normalmente ocurre por tenerlo en un fichero .js separado o por no haberlo subido al servidor. Si tienes la página en una URL pública y la puedes poner, podemos comprobar el error de lo que tienes corriendo en dicho servidor

Comment: De hecho tanto la funcion como el boton estan en el mismo documento, primero creo el boton y al final esta la funcion.

Puedes ver la pagina aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/kugwf1ys/

Comment: Invocar funciones directamente desde los elementos HTML puede considerarse una mala práctica. Te obliga a hurgar en todos tus HTML si ocurre algún cambio en el nombre de la función o algo. Es mejor agregar un *listener*  al botón, usando el `id` del mismo y llamar a la función desde ese *listener*. Y conviene también ponerlo todo dentro de un bloque que verique que el DOM está cargado... De todos modos, como ya te han comentado, debes incluir la función **antes del botón, no después**, porque de lo contrario, no la encontrará o puedes que des click en el botón y la función aún no esté cargada.

Comment: Ya intente incluirla al principio, pero me tira este error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at postRefreshPage (maps.php:68)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (maps.php:87)`

Comment: En mi primer respuesta esta el fiddle del codigo, por si gustas revisarlo

Comment: Sospecho que la línea del error es esta: `document.getElementById('hidden_form_container').appendChild(theForm);` ... en tu DOM hay un contenedor cuyo id sea `hidden_form_container`?

Comment: Si, esta al final del <body>: `<div id="hidden_form_container" style="display:none;"></div>`

Comment: Realmente, la organización del código que aparece en el fiddle es algo desastrosa, con todo respeto, tienes código Javascript por todas partes, tienes código duplicado... y ese mensaje parece indicar con toda claridad que se intenta usar un elemento del DOM antes de que el mismo exista, porque cuando se usa el DOM no está cargado del todo o lo que sea. Todo el código JS debería estar después de `$(document).ready(function(){  ...` ¿Podrías decir lo que hay en las líneas `68` y `87` del archivo `maps.php`... suponiendo que no has modificado el archivo desde el último error que indicas...?

Comment: No te preocupes amigo, toda critica es buena. En la linea 68 esta esto (js): `theForm.appendChild(newInput1);` y en la 87 esto (php): `$_SESSION['pagina_actual'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Comment: De hecho si debo checar mejor mi organizacion de codigo, ya que al parecer no funcionaba por que en algun lado del codigo me falto cerrar una etiqueta o una funcion, muchas gracias por el consejo

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de utilizar el atributo `onclick` sería mejor que uses un `EventListener` de JavaScript

Por ejemplo;

```js
function funcionEjemplo()
{
alert("Click");
}

document.getElementById("ejemplo").addEventListener("click", funcionEjemplo);
```

```html
<button id="ejemplo">Soy un botón</button>
```

Te dejo la documentación de [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com) del método **[addEventListener()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)** ya que sería interesante que le pegues una mirada!

Para tu caso, te dejo el [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8as71gfr/) de tu caso particular, pero con el concepto del ejemplo anterior asumo que te quedará claro como solucionarlo!

Saludos!